# Trying to debug error in first python code ever

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying my hand at Python to help me automate my trading strategies. Please help me out by telling what's wrong with this code:

```
d3 = []
n = df.count()
i = 0
while (i < n) :
    d3[i] = df[i:i+6].mean()
    i = i + 1
print(d3)
```

Comment: What was the error you got when you  ran it? Or, if no error, how does the actual output differ from what you expected? As a new contributer, there are three things you should generally always provide: (1) The shortest, complete code that exhibits the problem; (2) What you wanted to happen; and (3) What actually happened.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will make it a point to past the error message next time onwards. Here is the error message:

Answer (score 0):

`n` object which you defined by `df.count()` is a Series object which is just One-dimensional ndarray with axis labels.

[pandas.Series Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html)

Possible solution should look like that one below.

```
d3 = []

n = int(df.count())

n_obs = 6 # Window shift

for el in range(n-n_obs):
    d3.append(df[el:el+n_obs].mean())
print(d3)
```